# Adding attributes to functions outside function scope

Tags: python, django, django-views

Does this add new attributes to the view function in the View Class of python?

This is the definition of as_view() function in View class of view.generic.base module.

```
@classonlymethod
def as_view(cls, **initkwargs):
    """Main entry point for a request-response process."""
    for key in initkwargs:
        if key in cls.http_method_names:
            raise TypeError(
                "The method name %s is not accepted as a keyword argument "
                "to %s()." % (key, cls.__name__)
            )
        if not hasattr(cls, key):
            raise TypeError(
                "%s() received an invalid keyword %r. as_view "
                "only accepts arguments that are already "
                "attributes of the class." % (cls.__name__, key)
            )

    def view(request, *args, **kwargs):
        self = cls(**initkwargs)
        self.setup(request, *args, **kwargs)
        if not hasattr(self, "request"):
            raise AttributeError(
                "%s instance has no 'request' attribute. Did you override "
                "setup() and forget to call super()?" % cls.__name__
            )
        return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

    view.view_class = cls
    view.view_initkwargs = initkwargs

    # __name__ and __qualname__ are intentionally left unchanged as
    # view_class should be used to robustly determine the name of the view
    # instead.
    view.__doc__ = cls.__doc__
    view.__module__ = cls.__module__
    view.__annotations__ = cls.dispatch.__annotations__
    # Copy possible attributes set by decorators, e.g. @csrf_exempt, from
    # the dispatch method.
    view.__dict__.update(cls.dispatch.__dict__)

    # Mark the callback if the view class is async.
    if cls.view_is_async:
        markcoroutinefunction(view)

    return view
```

What does these lines imply?

```
view.view_class = cls

view.view_initkwargs = initkwargs

view.__doc__ = cls.__doc__
        
view.__module__ = cls.__module__
        
view.__annotations__ = cls.dispatch.__annotations__
        
view.__dict__.update(cls.dispatch.__dict__)
```

Does this add new attributes to the view() function?

If so why this works?

```
def main():
  def child():
    print ("I represent : "+ x)
  child.x = "Child Function"
  return child
print(main().x)
```

Output: Child Function

```
def main():
  def child():
    print ("I represent : "+ x)
  child.x = "Child Function"
  return child
main()()
```

And this gives Error?

Comment: The attributes of a function object are *utterly unrelated* to the variables used when calling that function.  Your "working" example only works because `child()` is never actually called; if it was, you'd get exactly the same error as the non-working example.

Comment: Yeah got it. Learnt it that python functions are treated as first class objects, which means they can have attributes. Whenever we define a function, there are certain attributes which it contains, and we can see it all through dir(method_name). One such attribute in it is =__dict__ which contains add on attributes which we externally add to the method. At the beginning this attribute method_name.__dict__ = {} contains empty dictionary. As we add attributes method_name.x = "Hi", then method_name.__dict__ contains {'x': 'Hi'}.

Comment: Also, the externally added attribute i.e"x" which gets added to the \__dict\__ attribute as key-value pair, also gets added to the existing attribute list along with \__dict\__ and other attributes. Now we can see "x" as an attribute in dir(method_name)